# Method to return Floating Images from Word document

Tags: ms-word, office-js

In Office.ks Word API, using the `body.inlinePictures` property returns a collection collection of `inlinePicture` objects from the body.

Is there a way to return a collection of "floating images" from the body?

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a `floatingImages` collection or `floatingImage` object surfaced in the Word API.

I would recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding this suggestion.